# More Elegant Mathematical Solution For Switch(Case) Statement

Tags: c++, switch-statement, sudoku

I Am currently working on a Sudoku solve project to work my way through the various C++ Skills from beginner to the more advanced (one step at a time)

I am currently in need of some sort of formula/solution to calculating the X and Y co-ordinates of the first "cell" in the 3x3 Grids found in a sudoku 9x9 grid.

If a sudoku grid's 3x3 sections were numbered as followed:

```
|  0  |  1  |  2  |
|  3  |  4  |  5  |
|  6  |  7  |  8  |
```

At the moment the best I can come up with is a switch/case statement:

```
    switch(cubeNum) {
        case 0:
        case 1:
        case 2:
            startY = 0;
            break;
        case 3:
        case 4:
        case 5:
            startY = 3;
            break;
        case 6:
        case 7:
        case 8:
            startY = 6;
            break;
    }
    switch(cubeNum) {
        case 0:
        case 3:
        case 6:
            startX = 0;
            break;
        case 1:
        case 4:
        case 7:
            startX = 3;
            break;
        case 2:
        case 5:
        case 8:
            startX = 6;
            break;
    }
```

I'm desperate for a more elegant mathematical solution (a formula/rule) or alternative to the switch/case statement to make this more efficient/less bulky.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

**EDIT**
I feel I may have been misunderstood. Consider the image below:

[image]

I am trying to return the X and Y of the cells coloured in green, as chosen by the large grey numbers that they correspond to.

Comment: It's all over Google. `y = loc / width; x = loc % width;`

Comment: You're going to have to explain that one to me?

Comment: @CaptainObvlious Doesn't look like he's actually after Cartesian x/y coordinates.

Comment: yeah, why `0, 3, 6` and not `0, 1 2`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
startX = (cubeNum % 3) * 3;
startY = (cubeNum / 3) * 3;
```

`3` can be substituted with `n` here you have n*n boards.

You'll have to apply floor to `(cubeNum / 3)` if, for whatever reason, `cubeNum` is float.

Comment: I don’t get why he needs `* 3`. I know that’s what he showed in his question, I guess it’s more a comment on his question than on your answer.

Comment: Explanation can be found in the comment to the question. Though I don't understand what he's trying to do, I just rewrote his switch statement.

Comment: @LordZsolt
But take 3x3 square number 1 (start co-ords should be 0,3)
Your maths returns (1,3)

Comment: Now why would it do that? (1 % 3) = 1, 1 * 3 = 3. (1 / 3) = 0, 0 * 3 = 0, thus (0,3).

Comment: Ach, I was working it out on pen and paper, obviously not using "mental floor"

Comment: Yeah, I did that often before I started programming 8+ hours a day :) Now it come naturally.